# I can't understand what values the function std::barrier sync_point takes

Tags: c++, synchronization, barrier

I'm trying to transmit the array *bounds* element values to the function *array_sync*.
The code:

```
auto array_sync = []() noexcept {
    static auto phase = bounds[i];
    return phase;
    phase = bounds[i+1];
};
std::barrier sync_point(bounds, on_completion);

auto array_work = [&](std::string name) {
    array_transform(bounds[i + 1] * n, bounds[i + 2] * n, num_array_1, n);
    sync_point.arrive_and_wait();
    array_transform(bounds[i + 1] * n, bounds[i + 2] * n, num_array_1, n);
    sync_point.arrive_and_wait();
};
// the cycle for threads output
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i += 2) {
    // the function for main thread
    array_transform(bounds[i + 1] * n, bounds[i + 2] * n, num_array_1, n);
    // new thread
    threads.emplace_back(work, bounds);
}
// threads joining
for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Tell me please, how to declare the function sync_point right.

Answer (score 0):

If I decipher what you're trying to do correctly, then

```c++
  auto f = [&, phase=bounds[i]]() mutable noexcept {
    auto result = phase;
    phase = bounds[i+1];
    return result;
  };
```

should do what you want. The way this works is:

1. `[&]` means that it captures the surroundings by reference, so you can use `bounds` and `i` and their values change in the lambda when they do on the outside
2. `[phase=bounds[i]]` gives the lambda object a named member `phase` that's initialized with `bounds[i]`
3. `mutable` makes it so that members of the lambda are changeable, so you can update `phase` in the lambda function body.
4. `result` is introduced because the function exits at `return`, so you have to change `phase` before then.

It's a bit hard to tell if this is what you want, though, because the code you showed never calls `array_sync`.